# spilt text files to tsv UTF-8 with headers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below code for splitting the huge file into 20K TSV UTF-8 files.

However, I need every split file to have the header in the 20k count, how can we do it?

```
$sourceFile = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\DE.txt"
$partNumber = 1
$batchSize = 20000
$pathAndFilename = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part $partNumber file.tsv"

[System.Text.Encoding]$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(65001)  # utf8 this one

$fs=New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($sourceFile,"OpenOrCreate", "Read", "ReadWrite",8,"None") 
$streamIn=New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fs, $enc)
$streamout = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pathAndFilename

$line = $streamIn.readline()
$counter = 0
while ($line -ne $null)
{
    $streamout.writeline($line)
    $counter +=1
    if ($counter -eq $batchsize)
    {
        $partNumber+=1
        $counter =0
        $streamOut.close()
        $pathAndFilename = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part $partNumber file.tsv"
        $streamout = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pathAndFilename

    }
    $line = $streamIn.readline()
}
$streamin.close()
$streamout.close()
```

Comment: What's wrong on `Import-CSV` an [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer..

```
$sourceFile = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\DE.txt"
# using a template filename saves writing
$pathOut    = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part {0} file.tsv"
$partNumber = 1
$batchSize  = 20000  # max number of data lines to write in each part
# construct the output filename using the template $pathOut
$pathAndFilename = $pathOut -f $partNumber

$enc       = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$fs        = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($sourceFile,"Open", "Read")  # don't need write access on source file
$streamIn  = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($fs, $enc)
$streamout = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pathAndFilename)

# assuming the first line contains the headers
$header = $streamIn.ReadLine()
# write out the header on the first part
$streamout.WriteLine($header)

$counter = 0
while (($line = $streamIn.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $streamout.WriteLine($line)
    $counter++
    if ($counter -ge $batchsize) {
        $partNumber++
        $counter = 0
        $streamOut.Flush()
        $streamOut.Dispose()
        $pathAndFilename = $pathOut -f $partNumber
        $streamout = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pathAndFilename)
        # write the header on this new part
        $streamout.WriteLine($header)
    }
}
$streamin.Dispose()
$streamout.Dispose()
$fs.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

A little different example using get-content's readcount parameter.

```
1..100 | % { [pscustomobject]@{number=$_;name='a'*80} } | export-csv 100file.csv

get-content 100file.csv -ReadCount 20 | % { $i = 1 } { $_ | convertfrom-csv | 
  export-csv ("$i" + '.csv'); $i++ }

dir


    Directory: C:\users\js\foo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM           1661 1.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:10 PM           8960 100file.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM           1831 2.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM           1831 3.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM           1831 4.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM           1831 5.csv
-a----          5/7/2021   1:17 PM            230 6.csv
```

I confirmed that a 1 gig file with a 20kb readcount used almost no memory.

```
1..10mb | % { [pscustomobject]@{number=$_;name='a'*80} } | export-csv bigfile.csv

get-content bigfile.csv -ReadCount 20kb | % { $i = 1 } { $_ | convertfrom-csv |
  export-csv ("$i" + '.csv'); $i++ }
```